# Add ImageViews to ScrollView in JAVA code

Tags: java, android, xml

I try to make a scrollview with imageview exactly like the scrollview in the logos quiz app.

I create an XML file with a scrollview.

> ```
> <ScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:background="@color/beige"
>     > 
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/layout_level1"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>     </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

and than i wrote this:

```
public class Level1 extends Activity {

Level1Draw L1;  
LinearLayout l;
ScrollView s;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    L1 = new Level1Draw(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);


    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_level1);


    l.addView(L1);


}
```

this is the Level1Draw class:

```
private class Level1Draw extends View {

        Bitmap[][] logo_1 = {{BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cellcom),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.channel1),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.doctor_gav)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.golfnew),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.globes_only_logo_acrobat),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.foxgroup3)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hando),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hafenix),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.haaretz)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.laisha),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.jerusalempostred),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.hop)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.maariv),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logodelta)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.renuar),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ravbariah),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pelephone)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shilav),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sano),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.reshet_tv)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.steimatzky),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.srigamish),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sport5)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tambur),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.supersal),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.superpharm)},
                {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yediot),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.walla),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tzometsfarim)},
                };

        public Level1Draw(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context);


        }



        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            canvas.drawBitmap(logo_1[i][j], 60*(j+1)+80*j, 60*(i+1)+80*i, null);
                }
            }

        }




    }
```

if i write a specific width and height when i add the L1 view, i can see the view in the screen but not as a scrollview, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: We need some more context; what are the Level1Draw object's width and height set to? What do you mean that you can see it on the screen but not as a scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

your "Level1Draw" class doesn't have an onMeasure implemented in it so it doesn't know what to tell its parent about the required size , and it also doesn't have a layoutParams when creating it.

in short , a custom view takes much more effort than just painting it .

in any case , instead of a linearLayout with a scrollView that wraps it , why not use a listView with imageViews inside it ? it's way faster ,easier , and memory efficient (imagine what would you do in order to have 100 imageViews ...) .

for more info , check this video out:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70